# Concatenating Column Values into a Comma-Separated string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table which looks like the following:

```
EventProfileID    ParamName       ParamValue
1                 _CommandText    usp_storedproc_1
2                 _CommandText    usp_storedproc_2
2                 _CommandText    usp_storedproc_3
2                 _CommandText    usp_storedproc_100
3                 _CommandText    usp_storedproc_11
3                 _CommandText    usp_storedproc_123
```

What I would like my output to be is the following:

```
EventProfileID    ParamValue
1                 usp_storedproc_1
2                 usp_storedproc_2, usp_storedproc_3, usp_storedproc_100
3                 usp_storedproc_11, usp_storedproc_123
```

However I am having some bother.  If I do a select on one of the event profile ID's I can get an output using the following logic:

```
SELECT LEFT(c.ParamValue, LEN(c.ParamValue) - 1)
FROM (
SELECT a.ParamValue + ', '
FROM DP_EventProfileParams AS a
WHERE a.ParamName = '_CommandText'
and a.EventProfileId = '13311'
FOR XML PATH ('')
) c (paramvalue)
```

However that just gives me the output for one EventProfileID and also I would like the EventProfileID as part of the output.

Can anyone give me any pointers in the right direction into how I can expand my code to include this and allow the code to be dynamic so that I can show all EventProfileID's?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
select distinct a.EventProfileID,
stuff((select ','+ ParamValue)
       from DP_EventProfileParams s 
       where s.EventProfileID = a.EventProfileID 
       for XML path('')),1,1,'')
from DP_EventProfileParams a
```

You were on the right track with `for XML path`. `STUFF` function makes it easier to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The original query does not work because it uses simple subquery (works only for one specific id)

To make it work for all ids you can use `XML + STUFF` inside [`correlated subquery`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Many queries can be evaluated by executing the subquery once and
>   substituting the resulting value or values into the WHERE clause of
>   the outer query. In queries that include a correlated subquery (also
>   known as a repeating subquery), the subquery depends on the outer
>   query for its values. **This means that the subquery is executed
>   repeatedly, once for each row that might be selected by the outer
>   query.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         EventProfileID,
         [ParamVaues] = 
         STUFF((SELECT ',' + d2.ParamValue
               FROM #DP_EventProfileParams d2
               WHERE d1.EventProfileID = d2.EventProfileID
                 AND d2.ParamName = '_CommandText'
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM #DP_EventProfileParams d1
ORDER BY EventProfileID;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/405571)**</kbd>

I strongly suggest reading [`Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL`](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Comment: Just like the duplicate.